# Rapsberry Pi without user and auto start node program

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

Before posting this question i have gone through different blogs but couldn't find any good solution so posting this question.
I have raspberry pi set up with pi user.

I want to set up it without login and run node program on start up so there would not require any manual intervention.

I am not able to edit /etc/rc.local file. It gives me Can't open file to write error. 
I am not able to open /etc/sudoers file as well. While opening it, it gives me error as well. So not sure what to do now. If anyone can help to solve this file issues and after that any good document to start the Pi without user and auto start node program will be so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start the Pi without any user.
And you need to be root to edit this file: `sudo vi /etc/rc.local` (on raspbian)

There is already an auto login process at startup, for the standard pi user, so you just need to add your command line for starting node.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

Comment: Hello I am not able to run the sudo command even. Ao how can i be root to edit this file. As i am not able to save this file after edit.

Comment: While running command sudo vi /etc/rc.local i am getting this error sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 1. sudo: no valid sudoers found, quitting. sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin.

Comment: Why do you want to edit '/etc/sudoers' ? "The default pi user on Raspbian is a sudoer." https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md

Comment: Have you made some change in this file ? Because there is a possibility of loosing root privilege by accident. I'm not a sudo expert and I don't know if this is possible to restore it back.

Comment: Looks like this problem is resolved. I reimage the sd card with latest version of noobs and i can login without entering username and password. I also can run the sudo command so it was sudoers file which was corrupted somehow. Thanks for your help.